# DJI SDK iOS 4.7 error 403 forbidden with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

I'm trying to install `DJI-SDK-iOS 4.7` using `cocoapods`. When I use pod install it shows me this error:

```
Analyzing dependencies 
Downloading dependencies
Installing DJI-SDK-iOS (4.7)
[!] Error installing DJI-SDK-iOS
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/0b/h5r2v83j12z2n4zymy15m0qc0000gn/T/d20181213-7776-15u9wjf/file.zip http://dh7g4ai1w5iq6.cloudfront.net/ios_sdk/iOS_Mobile_SDK_4.7_180823.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
[!] 'DJI-SDK-iOS' uses the unencrypted http protocol to transfer the Pod. Please be sure you're in a safe network with only trusted hosts in there. Please reach out to the library author to notify them of this security issue.
```

I've tried pod install `--repo-update` but shows me exactly the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Please use the latest DJI iOS SDK 4.8.1, 4.7 is old and has been removed from Cocoapods.

https://cocoapods.org/pods/DJI-SDK-iOS